# Return Dynamic MSSQL query from python

Tags: python

I have this script below. I left out the connection details for security purposes but the code executes with out error in python and in MS SQL 2019

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc


sqlInsertScript = """
SELECT 'INSERT INTO dbo.table(' +
    STUFF ((
        SELECT ', [' + name + ']'
        FROM syscolumns
        WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.table') AND
            name <> 'me'
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') +
    ') 
Select ' +
    STUFF ((
        SELECT ', [' + name + ']'
        FROM syscolumns
        WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.table') AND
            name <> 'me'
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') + ' 
From dbo.QueryPerformance
where EntryID > Number'
"""

insertquery = pd.read_sql_query(sqlInsertScript,cnxn1)
```

My issue is that this query returns 0 None in python. I need it to return the string I am creating because I intend to use that query going forward. I know the query works it returns correct text when run from MSSQL SSMS.

Comment: read_sql_query returns a DataFrame containing the cursor created by the query. Why do you think it returns the original query?

Comment: Not sure I follow your comment. This query is to return a string. I am getting a dataframe with NaN value.

Comment: By definition the method returns a dataframe,

Comment: Ok, should the string result not be returned as a result set in the dataframe? This is my question if I am not using the correct method please advise as to what package should I use for it to return my query string.

Comment: There is no string result. There is a DataFrame. You need to examine the DataFrame and you will see rows and columns resembling the cursor that your query returns.

Comment: The dataframe is empty the query returns 1 record but that one record is not in the dataframe.

Comment: The query is not yielding any rows. You need to double-check the SQL. Edit your code to store the SQL into a string EXACTLY as written. Print the string to the console, copy/paste into SSMS and observe.

Comment: As stated in the question the query returns 1 value (row) in SQL SSMS. The value it returns is a query string. I need that query string to be available in python. What is the issue with my code is there a better way to do this? I dont care if it comes back in a dataframe or a string.

Comment: "As stated in the question the query returns 1 value (row) in SQL SSMS. " - Yes. And, that row should be returned from read_sql_query  in a DataFrame with one row and one column. If you're getting None then something went wrong. I'm guessing that the something wrong is caused by the structure of your SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used pyodbc instead of pandas and your code worked for me.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
def connectToDatabase():   
    '''
    Connect to the SQL Server. Note the insecurity here
    '''
    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                              r'your server;'
                              'Database=your db;'
                              'uid=your uid;'
                              'pwd=your pw;')
    except Exception as e: 
        print(e)
        conn = None
    return conn
def getQuery():
    '''
    The query we use to extract data from our SQL Server
    '''
    # This can't go wrong so we don't need error handling
    query = """
SELECT 'INSERT INTO dbo.table(' +
    STUFF ((
        SELECT ', [' + name + ']'
        FROM syscolumns
        WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.table') AND
            name <> 'me'
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') +
    ') 
Select ' +
    STUFF ((
        SELECT ', [' + name + ']'
        FROM syscolumns
        WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.table') AND
            name <> 'me'
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') + ' 
From dbo.QueryPerformance
where EntryID > Number'
"""
    return query
conn = connectToDatabase()
cursor = conn.cursor()
# Submit a query to the SQL Server instance and store the results in the cursor object
cursor.execute(getQuery())
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

The output:

```
('INSERT INTO dbo.table( [A], [B], [C]) \nSelect  [A], [B], [C] \nFrom dbo.QueryPerformance\nwhere EntryID > Number', )
```

Here is the table I cobbled for this test case:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table](
    [A] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [B] [real] NULL,
    [C] [text] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```